# OpenBSD ISC-DHCP IPv6 not working?

Tags: ipv6, openbsd, dhcpd

How to enable dhcp for ipv6 in OpenBSD 5.5. Default dhcpd don't know about IPv6, it says that option -6 is incorrect and do not understand ipv6 config. But it has version 4.X that IPv6 must be enabled by default.
Does anybody know how to solve that issue??

Comment: Looks Like the only way is to use Dibbler server - it the one can be compiled very easily under OpenBSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard dhcpd daemon doesn't support IPv6? but if to install isc-dhcp from packages I've found that id doesn't replace it so to use IPv6 dhcpd I need to start it from path /usr/local/sbin/dhcpd.
And the second cool way is to use Dibbler server - it the one can be compiled very easily under OpenBSD. But relay doesn't work at openbsd.
Everyone can very easy to build from source.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking how to configure an OpenBSD 5.5 host as a DHCP client for IPv6?

Last time I tackled this issue I ended up using the wide-dhcpv6 pkg to accomplish it.

There's a [write-up at daemonforums.org](http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=7769) I made that may be of some help.

Comment: No I mean DHCP Server in stateful mode. primarily ISC-DHCP server 4.X